# Is there anyway to detect unix command "cat" finish merging files?

Tags: php, unix, file-upload, zip

I was wondering, is there any way to detect cat function finish merging a file, so I can zip the files?
for example if I have simple case like this, folder with multiple files like this:

```
/var/www/testing/file1.iso0
/var/www/testing/file1.iso1
/var/www/testing/file1.iso2
/var/www/testing/file2.xls0
/var/www/testing/file2.xls1
```

basicly, using my web app, user will upload file1.iso and file2.xls, and using html5 I will slice each file and upload it in part which will result at the above structure. After all parts of each file finish uploading, I will use an ajax call to merge the file using cat unix command.

```
$command = '(files=(' . $list_file_copy . '); cat ' . '"${files[@]}" > ' . '"' . $file_name . '"' . '; rm ' . '"${files[@]}")';
```

something like this.

```
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

My question is how can I know the file1.iso and file2.xls finish merging, so I can send another command to zip the file? as in file1.iso and file2.xls become filexxx.zip for example.

Please note that, the file could be multiple and each individual file can be huge (I will say 4GB at most, which is the reason why it will be slice 100MB to small part)

Comment: `cat foo >> bar && baz` - the `&&` waits for the previous command to finish before running the next.  I'm not sure if there is a more elaborate way?

Comment: @Emissary but at the same time, I don't want the user who uploaded the file waiting for the file to finish the merge and zip. It has to run in the background, so after the file part done uploading and arrive at the server, user can log off, or do anything else. instead of waiting the merge and zip

Comment: Possibly use some kind of naming convention in your merged file then have some cron command periodically scan for files matching that specified name/pattern and zip them.  Fairly sure the merged filed won't be written to the file system until the cat command has finished.

Comment: @Emissary no, the merge file will be written to file system as soon as cat command start. and then it's just the file size that will keep increasing until it's done

Comment: I just tested that - think you're right.  Could you perhaps then `cat foo > bar && echo '[filename]' >> logfile` then have your cron script read the logfile for merges that have completed?

Answer (score 0):

you could try and put a check for the exit code .......
when a command completes it does return a success/faliure indicator to the OS or calling prog....

in shell testing for the value of $? (would give you the exit code of the last command executed) , if thats a success it will return 0 as exit code - do the zip , else throw a warning or error as you like .

i do that in lot of my scripts.
hope this helps

Comment: in that case, the command will always give 0 because the command execute properly, but it does not mean the merge process finished.